# Detecting user inactivity in a desktop application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have an application in Eclipse RCP where I want to fire a function called 'LogOutUser()' if the user leaves his/ her application idle for, say, five minutes.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look in the bundle `org.eclipse.ui.ide.application` there is a class `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEIdleHelper` which tries to perform gc after a interval of user inactivity. Probably you can reuse the logic that detects the inactivity

Answer (score 2):

I usually use a `Display.addFilter(eventType, listener)` for the event types that should keep the session alive combined with a `Display.timerExec(milliseconds, runnable)` that is run periodically and tests for the last interesting event.

I use `milliseconds = 5000` so the period is 5 min up to 5 min 5 sec before the user is logged out (or whatever...). Also I listener for the SWT event types (in 3.7) `KeyDown`, `KeyUp`, `MouseDown`, `MouseUp`, `MouseVerticalWheel`, `MouseHorizontalWheel` `MouseDoubleClick`,  `Touch`, `Gesture`, `Activate`, `Iconify`, `Deiconify`, `Move`, and `Resize`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the RCP framework supports this internally.  However, I wrote my own "helper" class, which is a singleton client session manager.  Eclipse won't know natively how you connect to your datasource.  In my case I am connecting using EJB3 calls and listening to JMS queues and topics.

My class was written to detect when the datasource or "server" went down.  It would also reconnect when the server came up.  The server inactivity is detected by listening to heartbeat DTO's sent by the server.  This feedback is useful to present to the user.  I have adapted this class to cater for user interface inactivity.

The class is quite simple.  It is a singleton, so it can be called simply at any point in your client-side RCP application.  The heartbeat uses an observer and so you will have to add a `HeartBeatEventListener` to hook into this functionality.  You can adapt the class to do the same for the user interface inactivity.  However, I have just provided an `updateUserInterfaceActivity()` method which you must call when there is user activity.  Perhaps this can be hooked into a *global mouse* and a *global keyboard* event handler.

I have also added a `TrayItem` to update the user...

Here is the class:

```
package com.kingsleywebb.clientsessionmanagement;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolTip;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TrayItem;

import com.kingsleywebb.clientsessionmanagement.entity.HeartbeatDTO;

public class ClientSessionManagement implements HeartbeatEventListener {

    private static final Image IMG_CONNECTED = null;  // Set this to a "connected image"
    private static final Image IMG_DISCONNECTED = null;  // Set this to a "disconnected image"

    private static final long CONNECTION_INACTIVITY_TIME_MS = 30000L; // 30 seconds
    private static final long USER_INTERFACE_INACTIVITY_TIME_MS = 300000L; // 5 minutes

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ClientSessionManagement.class);
    private static ClientSessionManagement theInstance = null;
    private static long connectionTimestamp = 0;
    private static long userInterfaceActivityTimestamp = 0;

    private synchronized static void createInstance() {
        if (theInstance == null) {
            theInstance = new ClientSessionManagement();
        }
    }

    public static ClientSessionManagement getInstance() {
        if (theInstance == null) {
            createInstance();
        }
        return theInstance;
    }

    private ClientSessionManagement() {

        this.connectionListenerList = new ArrayList<ConnectionListener>();

        updateConnectionTimestamp();

        Cron cron = new Cron();
        Thread cronThread = new Thread(cron);       
        cronThread.start();
    }

    private boolean connected = true;

    private ToolTip toolTipConnected;
    private ToolTip toolTipDisconnected;
    private TrayItem trayItem = null;
    private String appName = null;
    private String version = null;
    private String whiteLabel = null;
    private String userName = null;
    private String deskName = null;
    private String serverName = null;
    private String userMnemonic = null;
    private MenuItem miShowPopups;
    private MenuItem miSoundBeep;

    private List<ConnectionListener> connectionListenerList;

    private void updateConnectionTimestamp() {
        ClientSessionManagement.connectionTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private synchronized long getLastHeartbeatInMsAgo() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - ClientSessionManagement.connectionTimestamp;
    }

    public synchronized void updateHeartbeat() {
        updateConnectionTimestamp();        
    }

    public synchronized void checkHeartbeatInterval() {
        if (getLastHeartbeatInMsAgo() < CONNECTION_INACTIVITY_TIME_MS) {
            showConnected();
        }
        else {
            showDisconnected();
        }
    }

    private void updateUserInterfaceActivityTimestamp() {
        ClientSessionManagement.userInterfaceActivityTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private synchronized long getLastUserInterfaceActivityInMsAgo() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - ClientSessionManagement.userInterfaceActivityTimestamp;
    }

    public synchronized void updateUserInterfaceActivity() {
        updateUserInterfaceActivityTimestamp();
    }

    public synchronized void checkUserInterfaceActivityInterval() {
        if (getLastUserInterfaceActivityInMsAgo() > USER_INTERFACE_INACTIVITY_TIME_MS) {
            logoutUser();
        }
    }

    private void logoutUser() {
        // Implement logout functionality here      
    }

    private void showConnected() {
        if (!connected) {
            connected = true;

            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Update icon
                    if (trayItem != null) {
                        trayItem.setImage(ClientSessionManagement.IMG_CONNECTED);
                        trayItem.getToolTip().setVisible(false);
                        trayItem.setToolTip(toolTipConnected);                      
                        trayItem.getToolTip().setVisible(true);
                    }

                    // Update hover tooltip
                    updateHoverTooltip();
                }               
            });

            notifyConnectionListeners();            
        }
    }

    private void showDisconnected() {
        if (connected) {
            connected = false;

            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    // Update icon
                    if (trayItem != null) {
                        trayItem.setImage(ClientSessionManagement.IMG_DISCONNECTED);
                        trayItem.getToolTip().setVisible(false);
                        trayItem.setToolTip(toolTipDisconnected);
                        trayItem.getToolTip().setVisible(true);
                    }

                    // Update hover tooltip
                    updateHoverTooltip();                   
                }               
            });

            notifyConnectionListeners();
        }
    }

    private void updateHoverTooltip() {
        if (trayItem != null) {

            // Application info
            String applicationInfo = null;
            if (appName != null && version != null && whiteLabel != null) {
                // appName* | version | whitelabel
                applicationInfo =  "  Application: " + "  " + appName + " " + version + " [" + whiteLabel + "]\r\n";
            }           

            // User info
            String userInfo = null;
            if (userName != null && deskName != null && serverName != null) {
                userInfo = "  User: " + "  " + userName + " (" + deskName + ") on " + serverName + "\r\n";              
            }

            // Connection info
            String connectionInfo = connected ? "  Server Connected" : "  SERVER DISCONNECTED!!!";

            String status = connectionInfo + "\r\n\r\n" + (applicationInfo != null ? applicationInfo : "") +
                (userInfo != null ? userInfo : "");

            trayItem.setToolTipText(status);
            LOG.info(status);
        }
    }

    public void setTrayItem(Shell shell, TrayItem trayItem) {
        this.trayItem = trayItem;

        /* 
         * Property files to persist these settings - removed for simplicity
         * 
         * final WorkstationProperties p = WorkstationProperties.getInstance();
         * boolean showNotificationPopups = !"No".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getProperty("notifications.showNotificationPopups"));
         * boolean soundNotificationBeep = !"No".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getProperty("notifications.soundNotificationBeep"));        
         */

        boolean showNotificationPopups = true;
        boolean soundNotificationBeep = true;

        final Menu menu = new Menu (shell, SWT.POP_UP);
        miShowPopups = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.CHECK);
        miShowPopups.setSelection(showNotificationPopups);
        miShowPopups.setText("Show Notification Popups");
        miShowPopups.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event event) {
                LOG.info("notifications.showNotificationPopups = " + miShowPopups.getSelection());
                // Property files to persist these settings - removed for simplicity        
                //p.setProperty("notifications.showNotificationPopups", miShowPopups.getSelection() ? "Yes" : "No");
            }
        });

        miSoundBeep = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.CHECK);
        miSoundBeep.setSelection(soundNotificationBeep);
        miSoundBeep.setText("Play Notification Beep");
        miSoundBeep.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event event) {
                LOG.info("notifications.soundNotificationBeep = " + miSoundBeep.getSelection());
                // Property files to persist these settings - removed for simplicity    
                //p.setProperty("notifications.soundNotificationBeep", miSoundBeep.getSelection() ? "Yes" : "No");
            }
        });

        this.trayItem.addListener (SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event event) {
                menu.setVisible (true);
            }
        });

        toolTipConnected = new ToolTip(shell, SWT.BALLOON);
        toolTipConnected.setText((appName != null ? appName : "<Application Name>") + " Status");
        toolTipConnected.setMessage("Connected to server.");
        toolTipConnected.setLocation(600, 600);
        toolTipConnected.setVisible(false);

        toolTipDisconnected = new ToolTip(shell, SWT.ICON_WARNING);
        toolTipDisconnected.setText((appName != null ? appName : "<Application Name>") + " Status");
        toolTipDisconnected.setMessage("DISCONNECTED from server.");
        toolTipDisconnected.setLocation(500, 500);
        toolTipDisconnected.setVisible(false);

        this.trayItem.setToolTip(toolTipConnected);
    }

    public boolean isShowPopups() {
        return miShowPopups.getSelection();
    }

    public boolean isSoundBeep() {
        return miSoundBeep.getSelection();
    }

    public void setAppName(String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public void setWhiteLabel(String whiteLabel) {
        this.whiteLabel = whiteLabel;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void setDeskName(String deskName) {
        this.deskName = deskName;
    }

    public void setServerName(String serverName) {
        this.serverName = serverName;
        updateHoverTooltip();
    }

    public String getUserMnemonic() {
        return userMnemonic;
    }

    public void setUserMnemonic(String userMnemonic) {
        this.userMnemonic = userMnemonic;
    }

    public void heartbeatArrived(HeartbeatDTO heartbeatDTO) {               
        updateHeartbeat();          
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return connected;
    }

    public boolean addConnectionListener(ConnectionListener connectionListener) {
        return connectionListenerList.add(connectionListener);
    }

    public boolean removeConnectionListener(ConnectionListener connectionListener) {
        return connectionListenerList.remove(connectionListener);
    }

    public void notifyConnectionListeners() {
        for (Iterator<ConnectionListener> i = connectionListenerList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            ConnectionListener connectionListener = i.next();
            if (connected) {
                connectionListener.connected();
            }
            else {
                connectionListener.disconnected();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @author Kingsley Webb
     *
     * Check heartbeat interval periodically display warning to user accordingly.
     */
    class Cron implements Runnable {

        public void run() {

            // Wait 15s extra before 1st check
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.error(e);
            }

            while (true) {
                // Check every 5s - increase for better performance, but you get the idea...
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    LOG.error(e);
                }           

                checkHeartbeatInterval();
                checkUserInterfaceActivityInterval();
            }           
        }

    }

}
```

Some other supporting classes:

```
package com.kingsleywebb.clientsessionmanagement;

public interface ConnectionListener {

    public void connected();
    public void disconnected();

}

package com.kingsleywebb.clientsessionmanagement;

import com.kingsleywebb.clientsessionmanagement.entity.HeartbeatDTO;

public interface HeartbeatEventListener {

     public void heartbeatArrived(HeartbeatDTO heartbeatDTO);

}
```